# mysql update form not executing on first tried but work on second tried

Tags: mysql, pdo

I am trying to do a query and update that query on a same page by using form but the problem is I have to submit form twice to get it updated.  This code is ported from my last mysql project. My last project was search then query then update.  This one is query then update. I can't see why form doesn't get variable to it on first click.  Still learning PDO. Please point me to a right direction. Thank you.

```
 require_once ('control/control.php');

 $db = db_connect ();

 $stmt = $db->query("SELECT * FROM offsite_inventory WHERE category != '' ORDER BY FIELD(category,'Sparkling Wine','Rose Wine','Riesling Magnum 1.5L','Riesling Magnum 3L','Austrian Riesling','Austrian Gruner','Trocken','Kabinett','Spatlese','Auslese','Chardonnay USA','Chardonnay France','Chablis','White Wine 1','White Wine 2','Pinot Noir 2','Pinot Noir 1','Cabernet And Bordeau','Red Wine 1','Red Wine 2','Red Wine 3','Red Wine 4','Rhone Valley Red')");

 while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {

 echo "<tr><td width=\”50\">" . $row['code'] . "</td>   
      <td width=\"380\">" . $row['name'] . "</td>
      <td width=\"50\" align=\"center\">" . $row['instock_resto'] . "</td>
      <td width=\"50\" align=\"center\">" . $row['instock_home'] . "</td>

      <td width=\"100\"><form style='display:inline!important; width:10px!important;' name='inventory' method='post' action='" . $PHP_SELF . "?id=" . $row['id'] . "&instock_home=" . $row['instock_home'] . "&name=" . $row['name'] . "'>
      <table width='1' border='0' align='center' style='margin-right:auto; margin-left:auto;'>
      <tr>
      <td valign='middle'>
      <label><input style='display:inline!important; width:25px!important;' type='number' name='instock_home'/></label></td>
      <td>
      <input style='display:inline!important; width:100px!important; padding:3px 0px;' type='submit' name='instock_home2' value='update stock' /></td></tr></table>
      </form>";   

 echo "</td></tr>"; 

}

require_once ('control/control.php');

$conn = db_connect ();

$instock_home = $_POST['instock_home'];
$id = $_GET['id'];
$name = $_GET['name'];


$stmt2= $conn->prepare("UPDATE offsite_inventory SET instock_home = ? WHERE id = ?");
$stmt2->execute(array($instock_home, $id));

echo"</table>";
```

Comment: Action POST why $_GET[]

Comment: When I use POST on 'id', I don't get any id back at all.

Comment: Got it. I need a condition.  If row effect display updated stock. If not do nothing.